# Select top rows where last entry is March based on todays date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've written SQL to produce 12 rows based on todays date.  Basically it is a list of month numbers, month names and the year starting from the current month using GETDATE() and then adding one month on for each row and a year where appropriate.  I now need to limit this data so that only rows up to and including March are displayed.  So today I would want to see 4 rows for December 2014, January 2015, February 2015 and March 2015.

I've tried adding in an additional column where April is always 1, going up to March which is always 12.  I've also tried including another column for the row number, where 1 is always at the top, so the current month.  I just can't get my head around how to construct the WHERE clause to cater for this SQL being used throughout the year during subsequent months.  If it was just for this month, then no problem, but how do I limit the rows displayed up to March when it could be run during any month?

For the purposes of testing I have replaced GETDATE() with @DATE and have been setting it to various dates through the year.  The first part of the SQL looks like this -

```
DECLARE     @DATE AS DATE
SET @DATE = '2014-10-01'

SELECT CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH_NO,
CAST (DATENAME (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH_NAME,
CAST (DATEPART (YEAR,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) AS YEAR,
CASE WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 3 THEN 12
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 4 THEN 1
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 5 THEN 2
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 6 THEN 3
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 7 THEN 4
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 8 THEN 5
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 9 THEN 6
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 10 THEN 7
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 11 THEN 8
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 12 THEN 9
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 1 THEN 10
WHEN (CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) AS VARCHAR)) = 2 THEN 11
ELSE 0 END AS DISPLAY,
1 AS ROW
```

There then follows 11 UNIONs adding on 1 month value and 1 year value where appropriate each time, so the next bit looks like this -

```
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE) + 1 END AS MONTH_NO,
CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(month, + 1, @DATE)) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH_NAME,
CASE WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) < CAST (DATEPART (MONTH,@DATE   AS INTEGER)     THEN CAST (DATEPART (YEAR, DATEADD (YEAR, + 1, (@DATE))) AS VARCHAR) ELSE CAST (DATEPART (YEAR,@DATE) AS VARCHAR) END AS YEAR,
CASE WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 3 THEN 12
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 4 THEN 1
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 5 THEN 2
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 6 THEN 3
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 7 THEN 4
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 8 THEN 5
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 9 THEN 6
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 10 THEN 7
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 11 THEN 8
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 12 THEN 9
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 1 THEN 10
WHEN CAST (DATEPART (MONTH, DATEADD (MONTH, + 1, (@DATE))) AS INTEGER) = 2 THEN 11
ELSE 0 END AS DISPLAY,
2 AS ROW
```

You then have + 2 in the next bit of SQL, etc, etc.

The DISPLAY and ROW columns have only been included to try and come up with a solution and can be removed.  The above has become rather bloated over the course of the last couple of days as I have been attempting various solutions.  I just can't work out how to select the top 'n' rows based on where March appears within the 12 results?

Thanks.

Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much simpler approach that can do exactly what you want with a CTE-based numbers table.

First, get a list of twelve numbers inside a CTE, adding them to the date you started with until there are twelve months.

Second, use those months to perform your calculations and date names.

Third, go back to the CTE and check for the number that corresponds to the next available March, and filter to only include records up to that point.

Full code:

```
DECLARE     @DATE AS DATE
SET @DATE = '2014-10-01';

WITH 
    E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) s(N)), 
    cteMonths(N, D) AS 
      ( 
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
            DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1, @DATE)
        FROM E1 ) 

SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, D) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS MONTH_NO, 
    CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, D) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MONTH_NAME,
    CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, D) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MONTH_YEAR,
    N AS ROW_NO
FROM cteMonths
WHERE 
    N <= (SELECT N FROM cteMonths WHERE DATEPART(MONTH,D) = 3)
```